# Add tabbed fields within QField

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qfield, qfieldsync

How can data be organized in tabs within Qfield?

The "Advanced Bee Farming Demo" that comes with QField displays data organized in tabs (see picture below: *General, Picture, Issues, Review, Consumption*). I attempted to recreate this, but I have been unsuccessful. I can only manage to get my data to be displayed in a liner list.

What configurations need to be set in order to display tabbed data?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the demo project to you computer and explore the configurations. Try to download from here https://github.com/opengisch/QField/tree/master/resources

Comment: This is perfect, I've been hunting for this.

Answer (score 7):

In the drag and drop form designer, between the middle pane (Form Designer) and Right hand pane (widget settings) there is a green + button. Press this to create a 'container'. Give it a name (will appear as Tab Name). Choose the Radio button 'a tab'. No. of columns only applied to forms viewed in QGIS, not QField, but allows fields to span across the page. The drag your fields for that TAB - they should appear indented below the container - if not, you've not put them in the container.
There are also some widget settings for the container / Tab. For instance, as when creating a group, you can set conditional visibility based on an expression.
Oisin

Answer (score 1):

A further point, at least as of QField 2.5.5, is that in order for the tabs to appear horizontally, everything must be under a tab: if the first item is not a tab, then the tabs get listed vertically and so are useless, while if the first item is a tab, then anything that is not in a tab is not displayed at all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).